# Error while starting Admin server on WebLogic 12c server

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracle-fusion-middleware

After starting the Node Manager when I'm going to start the startWeblogic.sh this happens and the server failed to start. (username, password is correct)

> > Starting WLS with line:
> > /home/app/oracle/java/jdk1.8.0_171/bin/java -server   -Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:CompileThreshold=8000 -cp /home/12c/app/oracle/product/12.2.1/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic-launcher.jar -Dlaunch.use.env.classpath=true -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/home/12c/app/oracle/product/12.2.1/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy  -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader  -javaagent:/home/12c/app/oracle/product/12.2.1/wlserver/server/lib/debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=/home/12c/app/oracle/product/12.2.1/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/home/12c/app/oracle/product/12.2.1/wlserver/server     -Dweblogic.management.username=weblogic -Dweblogic.management.password=mydomain123  weblogic.Server
> > <Nov 5, 2020 10:59:22 PM IST>    <Disabling the CryptoJ JCE Provider self-integrity check for better startup performance. To enable this check, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultJCEVerification=true.>
> > <Nov 5, 2020 10:59:22 PM IST>    <Changing the default Random Number Generator in RSA CryptoJ from ECDRBG128 to HMACDRBG. To disable this change, specify -Dweblogic.security.allowCryptoJDefaultPRNG=true.>
> > <Nov 5, 2020 10:59:23 PM IST>    <Starting WebLogic Server with Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM Version 25.171-b11 from Oracle Corporation.>
> > <Nov 5, 2020 10:59:23 PM IST>    <"ResourceManagement" is not enabled in this JVM. Enable "ResourceManagement" to use the WebLogic Server "Resource Consumption Management" feature. To enable "ResourceManagement", you must specify the following JVM options in the WebLogic Server instance in which the JVM runs: -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+ResourceManagement.>
> > <Nov 5, 2020 10:59:23 PM IST>    <Version: WebLogic Server 12.2.1.3.0 Thu Aug 17 13:39:49 PDT 2017 1882952>
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:01:59 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:01:59 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:01:59 PM IST>    <CMM memory level becomes 0. Setting standby thread pool size to 256.>
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:02:00,625 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:02:01,159 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:02:01,719 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:02:03,669 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:02:03,692 PM IST>    
> > <Nov 5, 2020 11:02:03,732 PM IST>    <Server subsystem failed. Reason: A MultiException has 6 exceptions.  They are:

1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.deployment.DeploymentRegistrationService errors were found
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.deployment.DeploymentRegistrationService

A MultiException has 6 exceptions.  They are:

1. weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
2. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: post construct on weblogic.security.SecurityService
3. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService errors were found
4. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.jndi.internal.RemoteNamingService
5. java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: While attempting to resolve the dependencies of weblogic.deployment.DeploymentRegistrationService errors were found
6. java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to perform operation: resolve on weblogic.deployment.DeploymentRegistrationService

   ```
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.Collector.throwIfErrors(Collector.java:89)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.resolveAllDependencies(ClazzCreator.java:250)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.ClazzCreator.create(ClazzCreator.java:358)
    at org.jvnet.hk2.internal.SystemDescriptor.create(SystemDescriptor.java:487)
    at org.glassfish.hk2.runlevel.internal.AsyncRunLevelContext.findOrCreate(AsyncRunLevelContext.java:305)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
   ```

Caused By: weblogic.security.SecurityInitializationException: Authentication for user weblogic denied.
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.doBootAuthorization(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1158)
at weblogic.security.service.CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.postInitialize(CommonSecurityServiceManagerDelegateImpl.java:1272)
at weblogic.security.service.SecurityServiceManager.postInitialize(SecurityServiceManager.java:586)
at weblogic.security.SecurityService.start(SecurityService.java:130)
at weblogic.server.AbstractServerService.postConstruct(AbstractServerService.java:76)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090938]Authentication failure: The specified user failed to log in. javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: [Security:090302]Authentication Failed: User specified user denied
at com.bea.common.security.utils.ExceptionHandler.throwFailedLoginException(ExceptionHandler.java:62)
at weblogic.security.providers.authentication.LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.login(LDAPAtnLoginModuleImpl.java:380)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper$1.run(LoginModuleWrapper.java:117)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.bea.common.security.internal.service.LoginModuleWrapper.login(LoginModuleWrapper.java:114)
Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace

> 

<Nov 5, 2020 11:02:03,760 PM IST>    
<Nov 5, 2020 11:02:03,760 PM IST>    
<Nov 5, 2020 11:02:03,763 PM IST>    
Stopping Derby server...
Derby server stopped.

**Any help would be great. Thanks!**

Comment: Hi, did you look My Oracle Support site? I see this similar error kb article, https://support.oracle.com/knowledge/Middleware/2335646_1.html

Comment: @Patrick Bacon...Here in Admin server ldap directory isn't deleted. This issue is happening suddenly. So can you please tell me how can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

1)Open a cmd and paste this :

```
MKDIR C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security
echo username=weblogic> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security\boot.properties
echo password=YOUR_WEBLOGIC_PASSWORD>> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security\boot.properties

MKDIR C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\WLS_FORMS\security
echo username=weblogic> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\WLS_FORMS\security\boot.properties
echo password=YOUR_WEBLOGIC_PASSWORD>> C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\WLS_FORMS\security\boot.properties
```

2)Open folder C:\Oracle\Middleware\Oracle_Home\user_projects\domains\base_domain\servers\AdminServer\security.

And open the boot.properties file.

3)Enter your weblogic password and insure that there are no spaces after it.
Save the file and rerun your weblogic server

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is santosh kumar and I have resolved the problem

**Steps**

1. Rename the file name "ldap"   to "ldap_bkp"
   `C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\servers\AdminServer\data\`
2. Copy the location path of ldap field:
   `"C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\servers\AdminServer\data\"`
3. Open command prompt in administration mode
   it will open like this   `"c:\Windows\system32>"` as bellow:

   ```
   c:\Windows\system32> cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\bin    press enter

   c:\Windows\system32> cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\bin> set DomainEnv.cmd

   c:\Windows\system32> cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain>                 -- disappear bin

   c:\Windows\system32> cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain>  cd C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\security    press enter

   c:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\security> java weblogic.sercurity.utils.AdminAccount weblogic weblogic123  press enter  -- (weblogic user and pass "weblogic and  weblogic123")

   c:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\security>cd..     press enter

   c:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain>cd servers\AdminServer\security

   c:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\servers\AdminServer\security>notepad boot.properties
   ```
4. It will open file in notepad if file is blanck write there *password* and *username* like. If contents availabale edit the user and password as new (see below) and then save and exit notepad:

   `password=weblogic123`

   `username=weblogic`
5. In the command prompt in administration mode type:  `C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\servers\AdminServer\security> cd     C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\bin   press enter`
6. In the command prompt in administration mode type: `C:\Oracle\Middleware\user_projects\domains\ClassicDomain\bin>startWeblogic.cmd  press enter`

It will run with default loging and password : weblogic/weblogic123.